# Kill a java jar process before starting the jar file again

Tags: linux, jenkins, executable-jar

I have an executable jar file in a particular path, say `/home/admin/apps` . I am building the jar file through jenkins and copies the jar file to `/home/admin/apps` directory. After the copying, I also have another shell script(invoked from jenkins) which just runs `nohup  java -jar myjar.jar`. But before running the jar file, i want to stop the earlier running process. How can I do that? I want to run all these through jenkins without manual effort.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `pkill -f 'java -jar'`